# Creating a Shopping Cart using only HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table, cart

I'm not sure what to do in order to complete this project.  I need to create a shopping cart that uses only one HTML page.  I have the table set up showing what is being sold but where I am lost is the JavaScript.

I don't know how to link the "Add to Cart" button with all the necessary data( The name, description, and price) to be able to add it to the cart.  I don't need to be able to remove it from the cart, but it does need to show the total.  After searching online for a few answers, I've tried some things but just cannot figure it out.

Any help is definitely appreciated because I am completely lost at this point and am new to JavaScript in general.

This is the jsFiddle but that was a little confusing to me, because it's working differently on there than if I just went to Run in Notepad++

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/renavi/ATjvt/5/

```
function AddtoCart() {
  console.log('hi');
  var x = document.getElementById('Items');
  var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
  var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';
  x.appendChild(new_row);
}
```

The direct file is here

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/sutGWjSY

Answer (score 9):

You simply need to use [simpleCart](http://simplecartjs.org)

It is a free and open-source javascript **shopping cart** that easily integrates with your current website.

You will get the full source code at [github](https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js)

Comment: I've tried already, but it all needs to be in one HTML file + I still can't figure out how to get the information from one table to the other.  It has to look like how I have it set up already, I just don't know the JavaScript part to get it working right.  Sorry, I should have mentioned exactly what I had tried.

Comment: It's not working... I mean cart is not getting updated.

Comment: I found this in 2018 and noticed that the downloaded files were created in 2013. Any thoughts or recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

For a project this size, you should stop writing pure JavaScript and turn to some of the libraries available. I'd recommend jQuery (http://jquery.com/), which allows you to select elements by css-selectors, which I recon should speed up your development quite a bit.

Example of your code then becomes;

```
function AddtoCart() {
  var len = $("#Items tr").length, $row, $inp1, $inp2, $cells;

  $row = $("#Items td:first").clone(true);
  $cells = $row.find("td");

  $cells.get(0).html( len );

  $inp1 = $cells.get(1).find("input:first");
  $inp1.attr("id", $inp1.attr("id") + len).val("");

  $inp2 = $cells.get(2).find("input:first");
  $inp2.attr("id", $inp2.attr("id") + len).val("");

  $("#Items").append($row);
    }
```

I can see that you might not understand that code yet, but take a look at jQuery, it's easy to learn and will make this development way faster.

I would use the libraries already created specifically for js shopping carts if I were you though.

To your problem; If i look at your jsFiddle, it doesn't even seem like you have defined a table with the id Items? Maybe that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it's not that I don't want to use something simpler or something that might work better.  We were just told we had to do it this specific way or we lose points.  He didn't teach anything really, he just gave us the JavaScript we were supposed to use but since I didn't have a laptop for some reason my friend thought it would be smart to delete the file he gave us..  He basically said we have to do this in one HTML file, using JavaScript and not using frames.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a better idea to start working with a raw data and then translate it to DOM (document object model)

I would suggest you to work with array of objects and then output it to the DOM in order to accomplish your task.

You can see working example of following code at  http://www.softxml.com/stackoverflow/shoppingCart.htm

You can try following approach:

```
//create array that will hold all ordered products
    var shoppingCart = [];

    //this function manipulates DOM and displays content of our shopping cart
    function displayShoppingCart(){
        var orderedProductsTblBody=document.getElementById("orderedProductsTblBody");
        //ensure we delete all previously added rows from ordered products table
        while(orderedProductsTblBody.rows.length>0) {
            orderedProductsTblBody.deleteRow(0);
        }

        //variable to hold total price of shopping cart
        var cart_total_price=0;
        //iterate over array of objects
        for(var product in shoppingCart){
            //add new row      
            var row=orderedProductsTblBody.insertRow();
            //create three cells for product properties 
            var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
            var cellDescription = row.insertCell(1);
            var cellPrice = row.insertCell(2);
            cellPrice.align="right";
            //fill cells with values from current product object of our array
            cellName.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Name;
            cellDescription.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Description;
            cellPrice.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Price;
            cart_total_price+=shoppingCart[product].Price;
        }
        //fill total cost of our shopping cart 
        document.getElementById("cart_total").innerHTML=cart_total_price;
    }


    function AddtoCart(name,description,price){
       //Below we create JavaScript Object that will hold three properties you have mentioned:    Name,Description and Price
       var singleProduct = {};
       //Fill the product object with data
       singleProduct.Name=name;
       singleProduct.Description=description;
       singleProduct.Price=price;
       //Add newly created product to our shopping cart 
       shoppingCart.push(singleProduct);
       //call display function to show on screen
       displayShoppingCart();

    }  


    //Add some products to our shopping cart via code or you can create a button with onclick event
    //AddtoCart("Table","Big red table",50);
    //AddtoCart("Door","Big yellow door",150);
    //AddtoCart("Car","Ferrari S23",150000);






<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" border="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Products for sale
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Table
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Add to cart" onclick="AddtoCart('Table','Big red table',50)"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Door
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Add to cart" onclick="AddtoCart('Door','Yellow Door',150)"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Car
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Add to cart" onclick="AddtoCart('Ferrari','Ferrari S234',150000)"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" border="1" id="orderedProductsTbl">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Description
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="orderedProductsTblBody">

                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="right" id="cart_total">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please have a look at following free client-side shopping cart:

**SoftEcart(js)** is a Responsive, Handlebars & JSON based, E-Commerce shopping cart written in JavaScript with built-in PayPal integration.

**Documentation**

http://www.softxml.com/softecartjs-demo/documentation/SoftecartJS_free.html

Hope you will find it useful.

Comment: This code isn't very available actually.  The demo looks good but you have to sign up to get the download.

Comment: This script work fine for me, don't know who and why gave - vote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one page cart written in Javascript with localStorage. Here's a full working [pen](https://codepen.io/hellomev/pen/YzpxNvm?editors=0010). Previously found on [Codebox](https://code-boxx.com/simple-vanilla-javascript-shopping-cart/#sec-download)

**cart.js**

```
var cart = {
  // (A) PROPERTIES
  hPdt : null, // HTML products list
  hItems : null, // HTML current cart
  items : {}, // Current items in cart

  // (B) LOCALSTORAGE CART
  // (B1) SAVE CURRENT CART INTO LOCALSTORAGE
  save : function () {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart.items));
  },

  // (B2) LOAD CART FROM LOCALSTORAGE
  load : function () {
    cart.items = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    if (cart.items == null) { cart.items = {}; }
    else { cart.items = JSON.parse(cart.items); }
  },

  // (B3) EMPTY ENTIRE CART
  nuke : function () {
    if (confirm("Empty cart?")) {
      cart.items = {};
      localStorage.removeItem("cart");
      cart.list();
    }
  },

  // (C) INITIALIZE
  init : function () {
    // (C1) GET HTML ELEMENTS
    cart.hPdt = document.getElementById("cart-products");
    cart.hItems = document.getElementById("cart-items");

    // (C2) DRAW PRODUCTS LIST
    cart.hPdt.innerHTML = "";
    let p, item, part;
    for (let id in products) {
      // WRAPPER
      p = products[id];
      item = document.createElement("div");
      item.className = "p-item";
      cart.hPdt.appendChild(item);

      // PRODUCT IMAGE
      part = document.createElement("img");
      part.src = "images/" +p.img;
      part.className = "p-img";
      item.appendChild(part);

      // PRODUCT NAME
      part = document.createElement("div");
      part.innerHTML = p.name;
      part.className = "p-name";
      item.appendChild(part);

      // PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
      part = document.createElement("div");
      part.innerHTML = p.desc;
      part.className = "p-desc";
      item.appendChild(part);

      // PRODUCT PRICE
      part = document.createElement("div");
      part.innerHTML = "$" + p.price;
      part.className = "p-price";
      item.appendChild(part);

      // ADD TO CART
      part = document.createElement("input");
      part.type = "button";
      part.value = "Add to Cart";
      part.className = "cart p-add";
      part.onclick = cart.add;
      part.dataset.id = id;
      item.appendChild(part);
    }

    // (C3) LOAD CART FROM PREVIOUS SESSION
    cart.load();

    // (C4) LIST CURRENT CART ITEMS
    cart.list();
  },

  // (D) LIST CURRENT CART ITEMS (IN HTML)
  list : function () {
    // (D1) RESET
    cart.hItems.innerHTML = "";
    let item, part, pdt;
    let empty = true;
    for (let key in cart.items) {
      if(cart.items.hasOwnProperty(key)) { empty = false; break; }
    }

    // (D2) CART IS EMPTY
    if (empty) {
      item = document.createElement("div");
      item.innerHTML = "Cart is empty";
      cart.hItems.appendChild(item);
    }

    // (D3) CART IS NOT EMPTY - LIST ITEMS
    else {
      let p, total = 0, subtotal = 0;
      for (let id in cart.items) {
        // ITEM
        p = products[id];
        item = document.createElement("div");
        item.className = "c-item";
        cart.hItems.appendChild(item);

        // NAME
        part = document.createElement("div");
        part.innerHTML = p.name;
        part.className = "c-name";
        item.appendChild(part);

        // REMOVE
        part = document.createElement("input");
        part.type = "button";
        part.value = "X";
        part.dataset.id = id;
        part.className = "c-del cart";
        part.addEventListener("click", cart.remove);
        item.appendChild(part);

        // QUANTITY
        part = document.createElement("input");
        part.type = "number";
        part.value = cart.items[id];
        part.dataset.id = id;
        part.className = "c-qty";
        part.addEventListener("change", cart.change);
        item.appendChild(part);

        // SUBTOTAL
        subtotal = cart.items[id] * p.price;
        total += subtotal;
      }

      // EMPTY BUTTONS
      item = document.createElement("input");
      item.type = "button";
      item.value = "Empty";
      item.addEventListener("click", cart.nuke);
      item.className = "c-empty cart";
      cart.hItems.appendChild(item);

      // CHECKOUT BUTTONS
      item = document.createElement("input");
      item.type = "button";
      item.value = "Checkout - " + "$" + total;
      item.addEventListener("click", cart.checkout);
      item.className = "c-checkout cart";
      cart.hItems.appendChild(item);
    }
  },

  // (E) ADD ITEM INTO CART
  add : function () {
    if (cart.items[this.dataset.id] == undefined) {
      cart.items[this.dataset.id] = 1;
    } else {
      cart.items[this.dataset.id]++;
    }
    cart.save();
    cart.list();
  },

  // (F) CHANGE QUANTITY
  change : function () {
    if (this.value == 0) {
      delete cart.items[this.dataset.id];
    } else {
      cart.items[this.dataset.id] = this.value;
    }
    cart.save();
    cart.list();
  },
  
  // (G) REMOVE ITEM FROM CART
  remove : function () {
    delete cart.items[this.dataset.id];
    cart.save();
    cart.list();
  },
  
  // (H) CHECKOUT
  checkout : function () {
    // SEND DATA TO SERVER
    // CHECKS
    // SEND AN EMAIL
    // RECORD TO DATABASE
    // PAYMENT
    // WHATEVER IS REQUIRED
    alert("TO DO");

    /*
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('cart', JSON.stringify(cart.items));
    data.append('products', JSON.stringify(products));
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "SERVER-SCRIPT");
    xhr.onload = function(){ ... };
    xhr.send(data);
    */
  }
};
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", cart.init);
```