# pure js shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart

I'm trying to make a shopping cart with pure JS. I'm trying to dynamically create some divs with my products and buttons to increase/decrease/delete them, but I am stuck. Below is my function which is creating these divs:

```
function displayCart() {
let output = '';
for (let i in cart) {
    output += '<div class="card card-body cartc">' + '<p>' +
        '<span id="' + cart[i].name + '">' + cart[i].name + '</span>' +
        '<button class="minus">-</button>' +
        ' ' + cart[i].count + ' шт.' +
        '<button class="plus">+</button>' +
        '<button class="delete">x</button>' +
        '</p>' + '</div>';
};
document.querySelector('.cart').innerHTML = output;
document.querySelector('.total').innerHTML = totalCost();}
```

So the next step is to put events on buttons.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
if (document.querySelector('.minus')) {
    let name = this.querySelector('.cartc span').getAttribute("id");
    removeItemFromCart(name);
    displayCart();
}});
```

As you can see, it finds the first `.cart` span id and returns it to `removeItemFromCart()`, but this function should work in every div that I create, not just the first one. How can it be solved?

You can take a look at the whole project at https://enoltc.github.io/hw-2/ or  https://github.com/ENoLTC/hw-2/
[Creating a Shopping Cart using only HTML/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293977/creating-a-shopping-cart-using-only-html-javascript)
The difference is that I want to write my script in pure JavaScript, without using simpleCart or jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Shopping Cart using only HTML/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293977/creating-a-shopping-cart-using-only-html-javascript)

Comment: document.querySelector returns the first element that matches the selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector . Perhaps you want document.querySelectorAll()? Even better element.querySelectorAll() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) returns a list of all elements descended from the element on which it is invoked, which match the selector. That way you can restrict it to the specific div you're working with each time. The answer is often in the docs, if you take the time to search.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293977/creating-a-shopping-cart-using-only-html-javascript is not the solution for my question, the thing is that i want to write it on pure JS, without using simpleCart or jQuery

Comment: can you include your HTML? perhaps putting the JS & HTML in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would be best...

Answer (score 0):

So I did it this way

```
let buttons = document.getElementById("show-cart");
buttons.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    let name = event.target.getAttribute("data-name");
    if (event.target.className === "delete") {
        removeItemFromCartAll(name);
        displayCart();
    } else if (event.target.className === "minus") {
        removeItemFromCart(name);
        displayCart();
    } else if (event.target.className === "plus") {
        addItemToCart(name, 0, 1);
        displayCart();
    }
});
```